# Read/Write a large text file in WinRT only using StreamReader/StreamWriter?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I try to figure out how I could read and write a large text file in WinRT line by line.

FileIO.ReadLinesAsync respectively FileIO.WriteLinesAsync would not work because they work with a list of strings that is passed respectively returned. With large text files that may cause an OutOfMemoryException.

I could of course write line by line using FileIO.AppendTextAsync but that would be inefficient.

What I figured out was that I could use a StreamReader or StreamWriter like in the sample code below.

But is there really no native Windows Runtime way to achieve this?

I know by the way that Windows Store Apps are not supposed to read or write large text files. I need a solution just because I am writing a recipe book for programmers.

Sample: Reading using a StreamReader:

```
StorageFile file = ...

await Task.Run(async () =>
{
   using (IRandomAccessStream winRtStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
   {
      Stream dotnetStream = winRtStream.AsStreamForRead();
      using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(dotnetStream))
      {
         string line;
         while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for writing large files using a StreamWriter. The used memory stays low even when writing very large files:

```
StorageFile file = ...

using (var randomAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var outputStream = randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = 
           new StreamWriter(outputStream.AsStreamForWrite()))
        {
            for (...)
            {
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(...);
             }
         }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your assumpltion about list of string is not completelly correct. `FileIO.WriteLinesAsync` accepts `IEnumerable<string>` as a parameter. So you can just do somethig like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> GenerateLines()
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 10000000; ix++)
        yield return "This is a line #" + ix;
}

//....
WriteLinesAsync(file, GenerateLines());
```

As for reading of a big file, you are right, we need some custom work like you did in your sample.

Comment: Tried that. Causes an OutOfMemoryException when trying to write large files (tried to write 1000 MB). You can watch the memory in the task manager grow when writing line by line. Using a StreamWriter the memory stays okay and I can write the large file. I tried a DataWriter as well, but unless I invoke StoreAsync every x written lines (what makes it slow) I get an OutOfMemoryException as well. StreamWriter seems to be the best solution.